# MongoDb cursor not returning all documents in collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to iterate over every document in a collection and save them to an excel file. Currently there are 857 documents and I have confirmed this in Compass, but only 756 are being returned. What would stop all the documents from being returned?

At first I thought it was to do with my object mapping, but I reverted back to Bsondocuments and I get the same result. Is there something I am missing here?

```
                var db = client.GetDatabase("database");
                var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
                var filter = new BsonDocument();
                using (var cursor = collection.Find(filter).ToCursor())

                    while (cursor.MoveNext())
                    {
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)

                        {
                            ;
                            sheet.Cells["A" + i.ToString()].Value = doc.ToString();
                            i++;
                            Console.WriteLine("Documents found: " + i);
```

```
Documents found: 757
```

Comment: Review driver documentation for iteration, if your code is different from documentation adjust your code to match documentation, if you still have unexpected results reference documentation that states correct iteration pattern that you are following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongo's cursor returns documents in batches.  You move from batch to batch using MoveNext and then processing the documents in Current.   The code appears to this, but the counter i is reset to 1 on every batch.  You will want to do something like:

```
            var db = client.GetDatabase("database");
            var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("collection");
            var filter = new BsonDocument();
            using (var cursor = collection.Find(filter).ToCursor()){
                int i = 1;
                while (cursor.MoveNext())
                {                        
                    foreach (var doc in cursor.Current)

                    {
                        ;
                        sheet.Cells["A" + i.ToString()].Value = doc.ToString();
                        i++;                     
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Documents found: " + i);
             }
```

Alternately it may be easier to do:

```
    int i = 1;
    await cursor.ForEachAsync(doc => {
      sheet.Cells["A" + i.ToString()].Value = doc.ToString()
      i++;
    });
    Console.WriteLine("Documents found: " + i);
```

or if you aren't setup for async:

```
    int i = 1;
    cursor.ForEachAsync(doc => {
      sheet.Cells["A" + i.ToString()].Value = doc.ToString()
      i++;
    }).Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Documents found: " + i);
```